# Links at the start of content elements

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

TYPO3 adds these links at the start of almost every element:

```
<a id="c1427"></a>
```

where number is, I guess, UID of the element.

How TYPO3 render this link and is it possible to disable it for a specific FCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your TYPO3 Version. In 4.5 it is defined via:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.10.value = <div id="c{field:uid}"
```

If you use the TS-Objectbrowser, you should find it somewhere in tt_content.stdWrap.*

Depending on the rendering you are using, you could be able to add an if statement like:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.10 {
   # check the uid of the content element which is rendered
   if.isInList.field = uid 
   # do not render if content element uid is 1,2 or 44
   if.value = 1,2,44
}
```

For sure, it depends on your configuration, so you cannot copy & paste. And i did not test this code! But it should show the way to go:)

Comment: Thanks, I searched for it in TS-Objectbrowser and found out that `tt_content.stdWrap.prepend.dataWrap >` does the job. But is it possible to change rendering for every FCE based on the same DS and TO?

Comment: try: tt_content.stdWrap.prepend.debugData = 1 - so you can see which data is available. I am not familiar with TemplaVoila. But if there is a unique uid, it will be possible. If you have <a id="c1427"></a> more than once, it will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in tt_content.stdWrap.prepend that is different for any languages different from default language.

Try to put this typoscript in your template:

tt_content.stdWrap.prepend >

Answer (score 0):

```
tt_content.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="content-element">|</div>
```