# Templavoila adds links at the beginning of an element

Tags: translation, typo3, typoscript, templavoila

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12265957/621765) but it couldn't solve my problem. On a bilingual page I use Templavoila to handel my FCEs. To enable the translation of the element I added following code to the XML of it:

```
<meta type="array">
    <langChildren type="integer">1</langChildren>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    <langDatabaseOverlay>1</langDatabaseOverlay>
</meta>
```

In the default language everything works fine, but after that I copied a content to translate it. In there it adds an `<a id="the content id"></a>` before every translated element.

The complete string looks like

```
<a id="c1644"></a><div id="c609" ...
```

Where `c1644` is the id of the translated element and `c609` is the id of the element with the default language.

Is there a way to remove this anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in setup.ts:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.prepend >
```

found here: http://www.blog.jpk.in/2011/06/23/how-to-remove-unnecessary-anchor-tags-like-etc/